# How to groupby Datatable by a column and sum numeric columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, datatable

I am trying to groupby a datatable by a column and sum a numeric field, but I couldnt be able to do the sum. Here is my code that groupby the datatable.

```
DataTable dt_grouped_by = dt_data.AsEnumerable()
                          .GroupBy(r => new { LOCNR = r["LOCNR"], DEPTNR = r["DEPTNR"] })
                          .Select(g => g.OrderBy(r => r["CODE"]).First())
                          .CopyToDataTable();
```

I have columns called quantity_received and damage_received. I need to sum those 2 columns. How can I sum them in the above code?

Comment: what is the type of those columns at DB end?

Comment: You need cast column to decimal or whatever numeric type it is

Comment: they are decimal columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a grouping, which implements `IEnumerable<DataRow>`. So within that grouping you can use all LINQ extension method, like `Sum()`:

```
DataTable dt_grouped_by = dt_data.AsEnumerable()
                          .GroupBy(r => new 
                                        { 
                                            LOCNR = r.Field<int>("LOCNR"),
                                            DEPTNR = r.Field<int>("DEPTNR")
                                        })
                          .Select(g => new
                          {
                               Code = g.First().Field<string>("CODE"),
                               SumQr = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("quantity_received"))
                               SumDr = g.Sum(x => x.Field<int>("damage_received"))
                          })
                          .OrderBy(x => x.Code)
                          .CopyToDataTable();
```

As you see, I prefer the `Field()` extension method to the row indexer `row["x"]`, because it is strong typed. Of course I have to guess the actual data types. I also removed`First()`, because you can't convert one `DataRow` to a `DataTable`.

Comment: I really like this syntax, but I can't get it to work; it tells me that `r` does not exist in the context. If you're still around, I'd also like some assistance. Thanks!

Comment: @Jake Was just a typo

Comment: I appreciate your response! Initially, I tried using `g`, but it threw a lot of errors. In the end, I was able to make the syntax work with lists.